# Working with HTML forms and php

Tags: php, html, forms, math

I'm making a calculator-like web application that asks for user names, then displays their names on the next page and adds their score.  I have three problems:

1. The user names won't display on the second page
2. It won't add the score
3. Whenever you enter a score for player 1, player 2's score is reset to zero, and vise-versia

You can access the page at: ripdvd.x10.mx/index.php
Thanks in advance!

First page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Select Players</title>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="scoregen.php">
    <p class="par">
        <label for="player1">Please type in the one of the players first name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="player1" name="player1" size="17"  maxlength="17" class="textbox" />
    </p>

    <p class="par">
        <label for="player2">Please type in another players first name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="player2" name="player2" size="17"  maxlength="17" class="textbox" />
    </p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="button" value="Start Playing!" />


    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Second page(displays scores and provides a way to update them)

```
<?php
// Get data from HTML form.
//Gets the player names
$player1 = $_POST['player1'];
$player2 = $_POST['player2'];

$addScore1 = $_POST['addScore1'];
$addScore2 = $_POST['addScore2'];

$oldScore1 = $_POST['oldScore1'];
$oldScore2 = $_POST['oldScore2'];

$curr1=$_COOKIE["score1"]+$addScore1;
$curr2=$_COOKIE["score2"]+$addScore2;
setcookie("score1", $_COOKIE["score1"]+$addScore1, time()+3600);
setcookie("score2", $_COOKIE["score2"]+$addScore2, time()+3600);

//Reset cookies if reset button is 't', which makes it clear scores
if ($clse = t){
setcookie ("score1", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("score2", "", time() - 3600);
}


// Generate HTML form
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Score Add</title>
        <link rel=StyleSheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="post" action=" ">

     <p class="par">
            <label for="addScore1">Enter your score, <?php echo $player1; ?>:</label>
            <input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" class="textbox" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?php echo $oldscore1; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Score!" />
    </p>

    <p class="par">
        <label for="addScore2">Enter your score, <?php echo $player2; ?>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="addScore2" id="addScore2" class="textbox"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="oldScore2" id="oldScore2" value="<?php echo $oldscore2; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Score!"/>
        </form>
         </p>

         <form method="post" action=" ">
         <input type="hidden" name="clsc" id="clsc" value="t" />
         <input type="submit" class="reset" value="Clear Scores" />
         </form>
<!--Shows player and score-->
    <p class="par"><?php echo $player1;?>:<?php echo $curr1?></p>
    <p class="par"><?php echo $player2;?>:<?php echo $curr2?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just one quick observation without going through your code very thoroughly.  `if ($clse = t) {` needs to be changed to `if ($_POST['clse'] == "t") {` ...

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Reduce your code until you can find the parts that cause problems. And next time only post the part(s) you have a problem with, not the whole code dump.

Comment: popnoodles, no you don't

Comment: @popnoodles Why would you need it? I see no session used here... Cookies is an HTTP thing. Yes, you can use cookies for maintaining sessions, but that does not mean you need sessions to have cookies.

Comment: Max, do you need to use cookies?  I mean you're setting the score in a cookie but not the names.  Could you just keep everything in hidden post variables?

Comment: @Adam Plocher:  I've already tried using hidden variables, but they keep resetting.  I found cookies to work most consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made several changes to your code (including the removal of cookies - hope that's ok).  If you can live without cookies, try this:

```
<?php
// Get data from HTML form.
// Gets the player names
$player1 = $_POST['player1'];
$player2 = $_POST['player2'];

if ($_POST['addScore1'] == null)
    $addScore1 = 0;
else
    $addScore1 = $_POST['addScore1'];

if ($_POST['addScore2'] == null)
    $addScore2 = 0;
else
    $addScore2 = $_POST['addScore2'];

if ($_POST['oldScore1'] == null)
    $oldScore1 = 0;
else
    $oldScore1 = $_POST['oldScore1'];

if ($_POST['oldScore2'] == null)
    $oldScore1 = 0;
else
    $oldScore2 = $_POST['oldScore2'];

$curr1=$oldScore1+$addScore1;
$curr2=$oldScore2+$addScore2;

if ($_POST['clse'] == "t"){
    $curr1 = 0;
    $curr2 = 0;
}

// Generate HTML form
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Score Add</title>
        <link rel=StyleSheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
            <p class="par">
                <label for="addScore1">Enter your score, <?php echo $player1; ?>:</label>
                <input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" class="textbox" />
                <input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?php echo $curr1; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Score!" />
            </p>
            <p class="par">
                <label for="addScore2">Enter your score, <?php echo $player2; ?>:</label>
                <input type="text" name="addScore2" id="addScore2" class="textbox"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="oldScore2" id="oldScore2" value="<?php echo $curr2; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Score!"/>
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="player1" value="<?PHP echo $player1;?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="player2" value="<?PHP echo $player2;?>" />
        </form>

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="clsc" id="clsc" value="t" />
            <input type="submit" class="reset" value="Clear Scores" />
        </form>

        <!--Shows player and score-->
        <p class="par"><?php echo $player1;?>:<?php echo $curr1?></p>
        <p class="par"><?php echo $player2;?>:<?php echo $curr2?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note, I haven't actually ran this, but try it and let me know if you get any errors or still have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Select Players</title>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="scoregen.php">
    <p class="par">
        <label for="player1">Please type in the one of the players first name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="player1" name="player1" size="17"  maxlength="17" class="textbox" />
    </p>

    <p class="par">
        <label for="player2">Please type in another players first name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="player2" name="player2" size="17"  maxlength="17" class="textbox" />
    </p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="names" value="Start Playing!" />


    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

scoregen.php

```
<?php
    // Get data from HTML form.
    //Gets the player names
    if(isset($_POST['player1'])){
        $player1 = $_POST['player1'];
    }else{
        $player1 = "No Player"; 
    }   

    if(isset($_POST['player2'])){
        $player2 = $_POST['player2'];
    }else{
        $player2 = "No Player"; 
    }   

    //CHECKS IF THE ADDSCORE BUTTON IS HIT
    if(isset($_POST['AddScore'])){  
        $oldScore1 = $_POST['oldScore1'];
        $oldScore2 = $_POST['oldScore2'];

        if(!empty($_POST['addScore1'])){
            $addScore1 = $_POST['addScore1'];
        }else{
            $addScore1 = 0;
        }

        if(!empty($_POST['addScore2'])){
            $addScore2 = $_POST['addScore2'];
        }else{
            $addScore2 = 0;
        }

    }else{//INITIALIZES THE SCORES TO ZERO; OR SETS IT TO ZERO IF THE CLEAR SCORES BUTTON IS HIT
        $oldScore1 = 0;
        $oldScore2 = 0;
        $addScore1 = 0;
        $addScore2 = 0;

    }

    $curr1 = $oldScore1 + $addScore1;
    $curr2 = $oldScore2 + $addScore2;

    // Generate HTML form
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Score Add</title>
            <link rel=StyleSheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        </head>

        <body>
        <form method="post" action=" ">

         <p class="par">
                <label for="addScore1">Enter your score, <?php echo $player1; ?>:</label>
                <input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" class="textbox" />

                <input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?php echo $curr1; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="AddScore" class="button" value="Add Score!" />
        </p>

        <p class="par">
            <label for="addScore2">Enter your score, <?php echo $player2; ?>:</label>
            <input type="text" name="addScore2" id="addScore2" class="textbox"/>

            <input type="hidden" name="oldScore2" id="oldScore2" value="<?php echo $curr2; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="AddScore" class="button" value="Add Score!"/>       
        </p>
                <input type="hidden" name="player1" value="<?php echo $player1;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="player2" value="<?php echo $player2;?>"/>
        <p class="par">
              <input type="submit" class="reset" value="Clear Scores" />
        </p>

        </form>
    <!--Shows player and score-->
        <p class="par"><?php echo $player1;?>:<?php echo $curr1?></p>
        <p class="par"><?php echo $player2;?>:<?php echo $curr2?></p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

1) I did not use cookies here, you don't actually need it for the scores, you can use to save the usernames though.

2) You can actually just have one addScore button, but in this code it doesn't matter. it add the scores anyway.

3) I always check if a an element of the POST is set or if it has a value or not. So i put some checking for the scores and the names.

4) In this line of your code:
`<input type="hidden" name="oldScore2" id="oldScore2" value="<?php echo $oldscore2; ?>" />`
i changed the `$oldscore` to `$curr`, because the $curr score would be needed in the next submit as the oldscore so the score would add up.

Answer (score 0):

`$oldScore1` does not equal `$oldscore1`

and in any case you need to keep the **new** values to post to the next page

```
<input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?php echo $curr1; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="oldScore2" id="oldScore2" value="<?php echo $curr2; ?>" />
```

Drop the cookies and just use

```
$curr1=$oldScore1+$addScore1;
$curr2=$oldScore2+$addScore2;
```

It's also worth checking if the posts are set to avoid warnings, and making sure they are integers, e.g.

```
$oldScore1 = isset($_POST['oldScore1'])? (int)$_POST['oldScore1'] : 0;    
$oldScore2 = isset($_POST['oldScore2'])? (int)$_POST['oldScore2'] : 0;
```